# Android application actived and deactivated triggers

Tags: android, lifecycle

I'm looking for a way on Android to know when my app is active (running, viewable) and deactivated.
I know I can use the onStart methods but there's a problem with that:
if I switch to another activity, i don't want the app to think "I'm deactivated and hey, activated again!" not even for a short period.

Why I want to do this:
I need to subscribe to a server when the app is active and unsubscribe when the users goes to another app, this can happen in every activity of the app.
So when the user switches to another activity of my app, the app must remain subscribed to the server.

Are there some kind of broadcast I can catch just like the wifi status? Or do I really have to put some logic in every activity (a super class is not always possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class that extends Application and monitor the status there.

Comment: i'm not convinced, tracking state in an application class will result in first a deactivate message and then an activate message, no? I don't want to do a server call every time an activity is deactivated (because it's possible that a new one will show up), I can add a timer and check after somer time if no new activity is active, but that's not the way to do it I guess

Comment: What is it you're not convinced of?